# C++ Copy 32-bit Integer into byte array

Tags: c++, copy, integer, arrays

Is it possible to copy a 32 bit value into an array of 8 bit characters with a single assignment?

Say I have a byte array (uint8*) with the contents:

> 01 12 23 45 56 67 89 90

Is it possible to copy into this array (through casts or something) with a single assignment?
For example, copy something like 0x555555, so that we end up with:

> 55 55 55 55 56 67 78 90

Comment: Generally, "copying" (whether done by casting or `memcpy`) will behave differently depending on the native byte order or the CPU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
*( (unsigned int *)address_of_byte_buffer) = 0x55555555
```

Beware of the size of int under 64-bit code... you will need to find a data type that is consistently 32 bits under both architectures, such as `uint32_t`.

Comment: Right, I've tried that, but that only copies the bottom byte it seems. For example, with `char a[] = "blahblah"; *((unsigned int*)a) = 0x555555; printf("%x", a);` I'll see something like 0xffffff55;

Comment: As long as your byte array is a native C array (new uint8[size] ) then it should work - can you post some code? Were you trying to do this to some class such as CByteArray? That's not possible unless the class guarantees contiguous memory - and you really shouldn't rely on that.

Comment: You can't use %x on a char array pointer - it will print out the value of the pointer, I believe. Try printf("%02x%02x%02x%02x", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3] ). Also, better make that unsigned char.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reinterpret_cast` although you really need to wear steel-toe-capped boots whilst using it.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using std::vector;
    using std::copy;
    using std::back_inserter;
    using std::ostream_iterator;
    using std::cout;

    int a = 0x55555555;

    char* a_begin = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a);
    char* a_end = a_begin + 4;

    vector<char> chars;

    copy(a_begin, a_end, back_inserter(chars));

    copy(chars.begin(), chars.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ", "));

    return 1;
}
```

Output:

```
85, 85, 85, 85,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reinterpret_cast` to cast anything into anything.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0w9f63b(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this: 
    `unsigned long* fake_long = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*> (char_array);
    *fake_long = 0x55555555;`

But such a solution can work on a big-endian machine. To make it work in a little-endian machine (probably you want), you should convert endianness of your long variable.